# R-project zoo object: how to remove rows where data is non-numeric

Tags: r, character, zoo

I have a csv file that has 2 columns separated by a comma - the first is the date followed by what is suppose to be numeric data.

I load the data into R via the read.csv function which stores the data in a data.frame object with 2 columns. I perform some manipulations to transform the object into a zoo object with the index set to the date. So now the object has one column, which is suppose to be numeric data and the date index.

The problem is the data has the character string "ND" randomly scattered about. I want to extract only those rows of the zoo object that do not contain "ND".

yr2 is the zoo object of concern.

Example:

```
03/15/2011 0.63 
03/16/2011 0.58 
03/17/2011 0.60 
03/18/2011 0.61 
03/21/2011 0.67 
03/22/2011 ND 
03/23/2011 0.69 
03/24/2011 0.72 
03/25/2011 0.79 
03/28/2011 0.81 
03/29/2011 0.81 
03/30/2011 0.80 
03/31/2011 0.80
```

I have tried the following:

```
> yr2[!="ND"]  
Error: unexpected '!=' in "yr2[!="  
> yr2[yr2[!="ND"]]  
Error: unexpected '!=' in "yr2[yr2[!="  
>   
> yr2[!is.character(yr2)]  
Data:  
character(0)  

Index:
Data:
named character(0)

Index:
integer(0)
```

I would greatly appreciate some guidance. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it make sense to address the offending "ND" data before converting it into a `zoo` object? Does ND stand for "no data", i.e. should be interpreted as NA?

```
txt <- "03/15/2011 0.63 
03/16/2011 0.58 
03/17/2011 0.60 
03/18/2011 0.61 
03/21/2011 0.67 
03/22/2011 ND 
03/23/2011 0.69 
03/24/2011 0.72 
03/25/2011 0.79 
03/28/2011 0.81 
03/29/2011 0.81 
03/30/2011 0.80 
03/31/2011 0.80"

#If ND == NA
dat <- read.table(textConnection(txt), header = FALSE, na.strings = "ND") 

#if not
dat <- read.table(textConnection(txt), header = FALSE) 

dat[dat$V2 != "ND" ,]

#or

subset(dat, V2 != "ND")
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. But now I have another problem. I want to plot the zoo object. The data is basically a time series. What happens is that the data is plotted but the x-axis does not take the form of date which is the index. I've spent hours messing around with this i.e. creating data.frames, ts objects etc...    nothing seems to work. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I converted the dates using as.Date and that works fine. Now I just cant plot the data. I want the date to be on the x-axis and the numeric data on the y axis. I tried plot(dat[,1], dat[,2]) where the date is in the first column and the data in the second column. My R console hangs when I do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Lines <- "03/15/2011 0.63 
03/16/2011 0.58 
03/17/2011 0.60 
03/18/2011 0.61 
03/21/2011 0.67 
03/22/2011 ND 
03/23/2011 0.69 
03/24/2011 0.72 
03/25/2011 0.79 
03/28/2011 0.81 
03/29/2011 0.81 
03/30/2011 0.80 
03/31/2011 0.80"

library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(textConnection(Lines), format = "%m/%d/%Y", na.strings = "ND")
zz <- na.omit(z)

plot(zz)
```